# When should we reset search index?

Tags: search

**When should we reset search index?**

http://blogs.realdolmen.com/experts/2015/03/02/resetting-content-index-in-sharepoint-server-2013-why-and-how/

I found the blog above said reset search index when

1. ***"Search Service Application got into an unhealthy state"***, How can we know it unhealthy or unstable?
2. ***"making lots of changes to the search schema"***. As I know, If I add/edit/delete managed property (search schema) then I should doing the full crawl instead of reset the search index. is it correct?

any explain would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What my experience tells that when your have to reset the index(it is very rare)

- index corrupted
- one or all index component status is degraded
- You crawl completed sucessfully but you are not getting the search results.
- when you move the index location
- when Index location run out of space.

To check the health state of the search run this command Get-SPEnterpriseSearchStatus, also you will see error in uls logs and browsers as well.

I agree with you adding the content required full crawled followed by couple of incremental crawls. But in rare case you need to reset the index.

In nutshell, its depend upon on your situation. Please check couple of good articles.

https://www.kieferconsulting.com/blog/Pages/SP2013-Fixing-Search-After-The-Index-Drive-Fills.aspx

http://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/2012/06/12/sharepoint-four-tips-for-index-cleaning-aspx-2/

Answer (score 2):

You should reset index

1. Index gets corrupted - Example when search crawl is not getting completed in a timely manner. Search is not returning any results etc.
2. In some cases I observed new crawled properties where not getting created. This issue mostly got fixed by restarting search service and there where cases were it got created only after index reset.

I would suggest before reset try restarting search service then if it didn't resolve issue then only reset index.